# Implementing centralized login across multiple mobile applications on a single device, for Android, iOS, and Flutter platforms

Tags: android, ios, flutter, authentication

I manage multiple applications that utilize a common authentication server, and I need to implement a feature that allows users to add accounts. If the user enters the correct credentials and obtains a valid token from the server, this account should be saved to a list. This same list of accounts should then be visible on the login pages of my other applications, allowing users to select an account and authenticate with its token. Despite searching for a proper and simple solution, I have been unsuccessful.

For Android, using the AccountManager is recommended, but the data is lost if the centralized app that created it is removed. Ideally, the data should persist as long as there is an app using it. I have considered storing data on Firebase or a custom server using the device ID as a key, but iOS does not provide a unique device ID.

Additionally, Android's sharedUserID, which facilitates token sharing between apps, is deprecated. iOS allows keychain sharing, but it comes with its own challenges, and Android does not have an equivalent feature for sharing keystores, as far as I understand.

Therefore, any code examples or ideas on how to implement this would be highly appreciated, whether they are for Flutter, native iOS, or Android—it doesn't matter. I am open to any help available on any platform.

To be more precise, I want my apps to function exactly like the Yandex apps do with Yandex ID. I have not been able to find out how they achieved this, but their approach seems to work very well. (Please excuse any grammatical mistakes in my English.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.